# Taking percentage difference b/w average of values vs taking average of individual percentage differences

Tags: percentage, differences

I have two sets of data points: List A [x1, x2, x3...xn] and List B [y1, y2, y3...yn]. If I were to calculate percentage difference between the two sets, what would be more accurate:

a. Taking individual percentage differences (x1 vs y1...etc) and then taking an average over all individual percentage differences or

b. Taking average value of List A, avg value of List B and then taking the percentage difference between the two average values?

To add more context, both the lists are computational times for two different runs on same queries (times in A are for the version 1 of a program and B for the version 2). I'm running a performance analysis of the two programs and hence need to compare how much time on average it took for queries to run on different versions of the program.

Comment: Surely this depends on the details of the data structure. You might want to add some context on the relationship between the two vectors and what the values represent here and what you hope to accomplish with this calculation.

Comment: Please say more about why you want to analyze percentage  differences. That requires a choice of what to use as the baseline values from which to calculate the percentage _differences_: List A? List B? Some average of them? Depending on the nature of your data, you might be better off working with differences on log scales or with a generalized linear model that weights your lists more equally and doesn't require such an arbitrary choice. Please provide that information by editing your question, as comments are easy to overlook and can get deleted.

Comment: Sure, added more details.

Comment: It is not appropriate to average percent change or ratios.  I'd you are truly interested in relative change take the average log ratio then antilog to get median fold change.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, that went over my head (I understand what you said but not sure why its more correct). Can you please link a doc? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the section on Change in https://hbiostat.org/doc/BBR.pdf

Comment: Here are two related threads, [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555224/why-is-percentage-change-as-an-outcome-variable-not-appropriate-in-regression/555245#555245) [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/554250/best-statistical-approach-for-psychological-experiment/554261#554261).

Answer (score 3):

> I'm running a performance analysis of the two programs and hence need to compare how much time on average it took for queries to run on different versions of the program.

Evaluating "how much time on average" the versions differ doesn't require a "percentage difference" calculation. A simple evaluation of the paired differences could be all that you need.

If you expect that one version will tend to be a certain percentage faster than the other, instead of a certain number of seconds faster on all tasks, then you can work with times in a logarithmic scale. For your setup, examine the paired $\log x_i - \log y_i= \log (x_i/y_i)$ values. The average over all $i$ is the "average log ratio" Frank Harrell recommended in a comment. That maintains symmetry between the $x_i$ values in List A and the $y_i$ values in List B. Section 14.5 of his [BBR Notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf) nicely summarizes the problems with using "percent change" instead.

A visual evaluation with a [Tukey mean-difference plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot), again with times on a log scale, could help evaluate if there are systematic differences between the versions as a function of the average computational time of the queries.

Comment: Could you clarify why a lack of symmetry is bad here? It seems like the status quo algorithm is a natural baseline, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @dimitriy it wasn't clear to me from the OP that there was a "status quo algorithm" to use as a baseline. In that case, and if the fractional differences in performance are small, then there would be no harm provided that the baseline values are far enough from 0. I'd be more worried about whether a single "percentage change" value represents the data over a range of query complexities, hence the recommendation for a Tukey mean-difference plot.

Answer (score 2):

Approach (1) is more suited to your problem since you are interested in the average improvement/deterioration across a sample of queries.

You can either use a paired t-test on the two query times columns or simply a one-sample t-test on the difference between two times. These two are equivalent. You could also do the second on the percent change if that is more meaningful.

Another alternative is the exact Fisher-Pitman permutation test for paired replicates. I think I prefer the second since it is exact and the data is interval-valued, so the assumptions are satisfied. The t-test is described in virtually any statistics textbook. The FPPT is detailed in

> Kaiser, Johannes. "An exact and a Monte Carlo proposal to the
> Fisher–Pitman permutation tests for paired replicates and for
> independent samples." The Stata Journal 7.3 (2007): 402-412.
> https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0134

Here is an example in Stata where there are we have data for 12 cars. Each car was run once with a fuel additive and once without. The variables mpg1 and mpg2 represent mileage without and with the treatment, respectively. Each row corresponds to a single car.

```
. use "https://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/fuel", clear

. list, clean noobs

    mpg1   mpg2  
      20     24  
      23     25  
      21     21  
      25     22  
      18     23  
      17     18  
      18     17  
      24     28  
      20     24  
      24     27  
      23     21  
      19     23  

. ttest mpg2==mpg1

Paired t test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable |     Obs        Mean    Std. err.   Std. dev.   [95% conf. interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    mpg2 |      12       22.75    .9384465    3.250874    20.68449    24.81551
    mpg1 |      12          21    .7881701    2.730301    19.26525    22.73475
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |      12        1.75    .7797144     2.70101    .0338602     3.46614
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     mean(diff) = mean(mpg2 - mpg1)                               t =   2.2444
 H0: mean(diff) = 0                              Degrees of freedom =       11

 Ha: mean(diff) < 0           Ha: mean(diff) != 0           Ha: mean(diff) > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.9768         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0463          Pr(T > t) = 0.0232

. gen change = mpg2 - mpg1

. ttest change = 0

One-sample t test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable |     Obs        Mean    Std. err.   Std. dev.   [95% conf. interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
  change |      12        1.75    .7797144     2.70101    .0338602     3.46614
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mean = mean(change)                                           t =   2.2444
H0: mean = 0                                     Degrees of freedom =       11

    Ha: mean < 0                 Ha: mean != 0                 Ha: mean > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.9768         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0463          Pr(T > t) = 0.0232
```

We find that the means are statistically different from each other at any level greater than 4.6%.

Doing it in percent instead of the raw differences, you get something similar:

```
. gen pct_diff = 100*(mpg2 - mpg1)/mpg1

. ttest pct_diff = 0

One-sample t test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable |     Obs        Mean    Std. err.   Std. dev.   [95% conf. interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
pct_diff |      12    8.860323    3.761323    13.02961    .5817056    17.13894
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mean = mean(pct_diff)                                         t =   2.3556
H0: mean = 0                                     Degrees of freedom =       11

    Ha: mean < 0                 Ha: mean != 0                 Ha: mean > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.9809         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.0381          Pr(T > t) = 0.0191
```

Here the p-value is 3.8%.

Now for the FPPT:

```
. permtest1 mpg1=mpg2, exact
Fisher-Pitman permutation test for paired replicates


 difference vector | mpg1-mpg2
-------------------+---------------------------------
 observations      | 12
  - positive       | 3
  - negative       | 8
  - zero           | 1
-------------------+---------------------------------
  critical value   | -21


mode of operation:  exact (complete permutation)

Test of hypothesis Ho: mpg1>=mpg2 : p = .03125
Test of hypothesis Ho: mpg1<=mpg2 : p = .98046875
Test of hypothesis Ho: mpg1==mpg2 : p = .0625
```

Here the two-sided p-value is 6.25%, which is a bit bigger than what we saw above. I am not a fan of using 5% as a rigid threshold for statistical significance, so I would not make much of the fact that the t-test p-values are below while the FPPT is above. I would reject the null here for both.

A one-sided may also make some sense for your problem.