# Why is percentage change as an outcome variable not appropriate in regression?

Tags: regression

I have the task of building a linear regression model. I have some baseline measures, including pre-treatment clinical scale, and would like my response variable to be the change in clinical scale scores. Based on some resources I came across:

- https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-1-6
- http://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf

it seems as though I should have the post-treatment scale score as the response variable, while including the pre-treatment scale score as a covariate.

However, I am wondering why can't percentage change be used as the response variable beyond poor power as spoken about in the Vickers paper.

Any references on this would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: I don't understand the question; in what way are the references you provide insufficient to answer your questions?

Comment: I am asking if there are any strict violations in the context of regression modelling that come from using percentage change as the response variable? The Vickers resource focuses on power, and the Harrell arguments against seem focused on when there are multiple time points (I have only 2: baseline and post-treatment). I am curious if there are other arguments to be made against percentage change being used.

Comment: Percentage changes are routinely used as response variables in other domains, e.g. economics and finance. So it must be something related to the domain of research

Answer (score 3):

If you think of the before and after measurements made on subjects, they are two separate observations made at different times - which are correlated.  Instead of the delta as the outcome, one option would be to use the baseline values as a predictor in the regression model to "adjust" for baseline effect, and then use the follow-up values as the outcome dependent variable.  In this fashion, the baseline value would be "controlled for."

I would analyze the repeated measures, i.e., longitudinal data, using something like GEE regression (generalized estimating equations) for longitudinal data analysis.  Here, you stack multiple observations for subjects in "long format" like:

[image]

where in your data you only have e.g. baseline values at months=0, and say the 3-month values.  When running GEE, you have to first specify that ID is the cluster (subject) variable, and month is the time variable.  Then, regress score on months, and if months is significant and the regression coefficient is positive the mean values (delta) for score were significantly greater at 3 months.  Vice versa for significantly lower at 3 months.  If there is a treatment variable (0-placebo, 1-treatment), you would regress score on trt(0,1), months, and an interaction term for trt*months.  If the interaction term was significantly positive, then scores were significantly greater among the treated at 3 months compared to placebo.

The main reason why I got away from delta used as an outcome variable is because:

- A delta implies 2 repeated measurements on the same subject
- Repeated measurements are correlated
- Correlated (repeated) measurements as an outcome can be analyzed using a variety of longitudinal regression approaches (GLM-mixed, GEE, etc. )

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any major violations of a regression model when using percentage change as an endpoint.  I think the ultimate reason for choosing one of these endpoints over another should be interpretation.

As user0123456789 demonstrated (+1), a common approach particularly in clinical drug development is to model the post-baseline measurements longitudinally.  This allows for the comparison of the mean endpoint between treatments at each time point, i.e. the average disease activity score at week 52 when treated with the active therapy is 20 units lower than when treated with placebo.  Without the luxury of randomization one might be interested in adjusting for the baseline measurement.

If percentage change is the endpoint this allows for the comparison of mean percentage change in the endpoint between treatments at each time point.  For the purposes of comparative effectiveness this works just fine.  For the purposes of providing an interpretable treatment effect, it is not very helpful, i.e. the average percentage change in disease activity score at week 52 when treated with the active therapy is 30 percentage change points lower than when treated with placebo.  Here we are not comparing mean scores between groups, we are comparing mean rates of change between groups.

There are other options such as modeling change from baseline in clinical score or modeling the clinical score longitudinally with baseline scores as a dependent variable.  These approaches allow for the comparison between treatments of mean differences, but can lead to slightly different results depending on missing data.